# xjc does not handle underscores properly

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

Very simple usecase. Translate the following XSD to java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="Foo_Bar">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="choices" type="TypeMyEnum" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="TypeMyEnum">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="ALPHA_1_0_0"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="BETA_2_0_0"/>
      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType> 
</xs:schema>
```

By default, xjc will create a file called FooBar.java and a file called TypeMyEnum.java. Notice how xjc "ate" the underscore in Foo_Bar. Also, by default, the internals of TypeMyEnum look like this:

```
ALPHA_1_0_0,
BETA_2_0_0;
```

To get the underscore back in Foo_Bar, I have to use a bindings file as follows:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Now, the code generates a Foo_Bar.java file as desired but horribly changes the internals of TypeMyEnum to look like:

```
@XmlEnumValue("ALPHA_1_0_0")
ALPHA___1___0___0("ALPHA_1_0_0"),
@XmlEnumValue("BETA_2_0_0")
BETA___2___0___0("BETA_2_0_0");
private final String value;
```

It seems every underscore in an enum value is changed to three underscores. This is easily reproducible and beyond me why xjc would do this.

Is there any way to get xjc to retain the underscore in the class name (i.e Foo_Bar.java) AND generate a sane enum file? I do not want to get into the business of generating specific bindings for every enum in my schema.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?